# Intent.createChooser not creating full list

Tags: java, android, messaging

After working on creating a small android app, I have a text field in which I'd like to share the text within it. Everything works fine until the Intent which causes it to share. I have it set up exactly as it is on the training page:

http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

Just like this:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to));
```

I'm using exactly their code for debugging purposes, but when I press the button, I only get a list of 4 apps, (AndFTP, Bluetooth, Drive, and Facebook) when I have many more apps that should be able to receive the data (e.g. Twitter, Messaging, Gmail, etc.) What do I do?

**--EDIT--**

I forgot to mention my device is the Droid DNA, for I feel this problem may have something to do with HTC sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old, but was a dumb mistake on my part, not fully understanding the UI